# How to send a keypress

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to modify a script that checks for fullscreen.
Currently it opens a message box saying the window is fullscreen or not.

I want to change it so it sends a key if it is not fullscreen instead of the msg box.

```
isFullScreen := isWindowFullScreen( "A" )
MsgBox % isFullScreen ? "Full Screen" : "Windowed"
Return

isWindowFullScreen( winTitle ) {
    ;checks if the specified window is full screen

    winID := WinExist( winTitle )

    If ( !winID )
        Return false

    WinGet style, Style, ahk_id %WinID%
    WinGetPos ,,,winW,winH, %winTitle%
    ; 0x800000 is WS_BORDER.
    ; 0x20000000 is WS_MINIMIZE.
    ; no border and not minimized
    Return ((style & 0x20800000) or winH < A_ScreenHeight or winW < A_ScreenWidth) ? false : true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [send](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Send.htm) or `sendPlay` command (see the linked documentation for the list of hotkeys).

```
if (isFullScreen) {
   ;...............
} else {
  sendPlay {Enter}
}
```